# Symfony2 custom console command not working

Tags: symfony

I created a new Class in src/MaintenanceBundle/Command, named it GreetCommand.php and put the following code in it:

```
<?php

namespace SK2\MaintenanceBundle\Command;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Command\ContainerAwareCommand;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputArgument;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputOption;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;

class GreetCommand extends ContainerAwareCommand
{
    protected function configure()
    {
        $this
            ->setName('maintenance:greet')
            ->setDescription('Greet someone')
            ->addArgument('name', InputArgument::OPTIONAL, 'Who do you want to greet?')
            ->addOption('yell', null, InputOption::VALUE_NONE, 'If set, the task will yell in uppercase letters')
        ;
    }

    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        $name = $input->getArgument('name');
        if ($name) {
            $text = 'Hello '.$name;
        } else {
            $text = 'Hello';
        }

        if ($input->getOption('yell')) {
            $text = strtoupper($text);
        }

        $output->writeln($text);
    }
}

?>
```

And tried to call it via

> app/console maintenance:greet Fabien

But i always get the following error:

> [InvalidArgumentException]
>   There are no commands defined in the "maintenance" namespace.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you clear the cache after creating the command?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I figured out why it was not working: I simply forgot to register the Bundle in the AppKernel.php. However, the other proposed answers are relevant and might be helpful to resolve other situations!

By convention: the commands files need to reside in a bundle's command directory and have a name ending with Command.

in AppKernel.php

```
public function registerBundles()
{
    $bundles = [
        ...
        new MaintenanceBundle\MaintenanceBundle(),
    ];

    return $bundles;
}
```

Answer (score 60):

I had this problem, and it was because the name of my PHP class and file didn't end with `Command`.

Symfony will automatically register commands which end with `Command` and are in the `Command` directory of a bundle.  If you'd like to *manually* register your command, this cookbook entry may help: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/console/commands_as_services.html

Comment: This one got me. You have store you commands in a bundle's Command directory and name your command class with Command at the end. Then Symfony will auto-register everything correctly.

Comment: I've just had this issue and it was because the file name didn't have 'Command' on the end of it - so it's not just the name space or directory name/location that can cause this one.

Comment: Thanks @ScottFlack.  I've updated my post to make it clearer that the filename must also end with `command`, not just the class name.

Answer (score 22):

I had a similar problem and figured out another possible solution:

If you override the default `__construct` method the Command will not be auto-registered by Symfony, so you have to either take the service approach as mentioned earlier or remove the `__construct` override and make that init step in the execute method or in the configure method.

Does actually anyone know a good best practice how to do init "stuff" in Symfony commands?

It took me a moment to figure this out.

Comment: This one got me. Cheers. Back to setter injection!

Answer (score 2):

In addition to MonocroM's answer, I had the same issue with my command and was silently ignored by Symfony only because my command's constructor had 1 required argument.

I just removed it and call the parent `__construct()` method (Symfony 2.7) and it worked well ;)

Answer (score 2):

If you are over-riding the command constructor and are using lazy-loading/autowiring, then your commands will not be automatically registered. To fix this you can add a `$defaultName` variable:

```
class SunshineCommand extends Command
{
    protected static $defaultName = 'app:sunshine';

    // ...
}
```

Link to the [Symfony docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/console/commands_as_services.html).

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to call `parent::configure()` in your `configure` method

Answer (score 1):

I had this same error when I tried to test my command execution with PHPUnit.

This was due to a wrong class import :

```
use Symfony\Component\Console\Application;
```

should be

```
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application;
```

cf. [Other stack thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48951967/2674501)

Comment: This was exactly the issue for me, curse blind importing!

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was complaining about the "workflow" namespace although the [`WorkflowDumpCommand`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/5129c4cf7e294b1a5ea30d6fec6e89b75396dcd2/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Command/WorkflowDumpCommand.php) was correctly provided by the framework.

However, it was not available to run because I have not defined any workflows so the [`isEnabled()`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/5129c4cf7e294b1a5ea30d6fec6e89b75396dcd2/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Command/WorkflowDumpCommand.php#L25) method of the command returned `false`.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to use a service passed via constructor inside the `configure` method:

```
class SomeCommand extends Command {

    private $service;

    public function __construct(SomeService $service) {
        $this->service = $service;
    }

    protected function configure(): void {
        $this->service->doSomething(); // DOES NOT WORK
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Symfony uses Autoconfiguration that automatically inject dependencies into your services and register your services as Command, event,....

So first just make sure that you have services.yaml in your config folder. with autoconfigure:true.
this is the default setting

Then Make sure That All your files are exactly the same name as Your Class.
so if you have SimpleClass your file must be SimpleClass.php

Answer (score 0):

If you have a problem because of a __constructor,
go to services.yml and add something like this:

```
app.email_handler_command:
    class: AppBundle\Command\EmailHandlerCommand
    arguments:
        - '@doctrine.orm.entity_manager'
        - '@app.email_handler_service'
    tags:
        - { name: console.command }
```

Answer (score 0):

For newer Symfony-Version (5+) commands must be registered as services.

What I do frequently forget while setting it up, is to tag it properly:

```
 <service id="someServiceCommand">
      <tag name="console.command"/>
 </service>
```

Without this litte adaptation, your command name will not be displayed and therefore not accessible.