# Symfony 3.4 - "no commands defined in the “doctrine:schema” namespace" when attempting to run console command in class

Tags: php, unit-testing, fixtures, symfony-3.4

I'm following along with [this blog](http://blog.joeymasip.com/symfony-phpunit-testing-database-data) to create unit tests that use my data fixtures as a base.  The relevant code:

```
namespace Tests\AppBundle\Repository;

use Symfony\Component\Console\Application;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\StringInput;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\WebTestCase;

class DataFixtureTestCase extends WebTestCase
{
    protected $client, $container, $em;
    protected static $application;

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    protected function setUp()
    {
        self::runCommand('doctrine:schema:drop --force');
        self::runCommand('doctrine:schema:create');
        self::runCommand('doctrine:fixtures:load --append --no-interaction --force');

        $this->client = static::createClient();
        $this->container = $this->client->getContainer();
        $this->em = $this->container->get('doctrine')->getManager();
    }

    protected static function runCommand($command)
    {
        $command = sprintf('%s --quiet', $command);

        try {
            return self::getApplication()->run(new StringInput($command));
        } catch(\Exception $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
    }

    protected static function getApplication()
    {
        if (null === self::$application) {
            $client = static::createClient();

            self::$application = new Application($client->getKernel());
            self::$application->setAutoExit(false);
        }

        return self::$application;
    }

    // other methods not relevant to the question
```

My unit test classes extend `DataFixtureTestCase`.  When `setUp()` is invoked, I keep getting errors like:

> There are no commands defined in the "doctrine:schema" namespace

Any ideas on what's causing this?  My research hasn't revealed the cause of the error.  Doctrine is correctly installed via Composer, and I can run the console commands manually in a terminal.

Comment: I think then the issue could be the working directory here. Do you see output of these commands? Can you print the current working directory in your PHP code and see if that is not what it should be when you run from terminal. Also you are missing `parent::setUp();`, I assume you shouldn't do that

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your problem is that you are using the wrong **Application** class for this.

Have a look at your **bin/console** php file. [github link](https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/blob/3.4/bin/console)

Change:

```
use Symfony\Component\Console\Application;
```

to

```
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application;
```

Answer (score 1):

`doctrine/doctrine-bundle` and `doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle` should be installed to run `doctrine:schema` and `doctrine:fixtures` commands

Comment: I wouldn't be trying to run those console commands if I hadn't already installed those packages via Composer :P

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by Denis, try adding Doctrine bundles via componser:

```
composer require doctrine/doctrine-bundle
composer require doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle --dev
```