# How to enable doctrine:schema namespace for bin/console?

Tags: doctrine, pimcore, coreshop

I'm attempting to add this bundle to my project: https://docs.coreshop.org/2.1.0/Bundles/Store_Bundle.html

I was able to add the bundle and activate it in the Kernel, but when I attempt the "php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force" portion, I get an error:

```
There are no commands defined in the "doctrine:schema" namespace.

  Did you mean one of these?
      doctrine
      doctrine:cache
      doctrine:database
      doctrine:generate
      doctrine:query
```

I've attempted to install various doctrine bundles I thought would include it, but it does not seem to make a difference.  I'm running on Symfony 4.3.

Comment: Verify you have Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\DoctrineBundle installed.  Not sure how you could have the doctrine:database command without getting doctrine:schema as well.  Symfony version?  Maybe start a fresh project.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Symfony 3.4 - "no commands defined in the “doctrine:schema” namespace" when attempting to run console command in class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48896818/symfony-3-4-no-commands-defined-in-the-doctrineschema-namespace-when-atte)

Comment: And it is not about Symfony

Comment: Fair point, I adjusted to be more specific.  I ran across that other post referencing the bin\console before I posted, but since it's a Pimcore project, it is a bit different.

Comment: Which Pimcore version are you using? Try `composer show doctrine/orm`

Answer (score 1):

Pimcore does currently not ship with the required packages. So you will have to require them manually:

```
composer require symfony/maker-bundle symfony/orm-pack
```

You als have to add the following to your `config.yml`:

```
doctrine: 
    orm: 
        default_entity_manager: default
```